# Angular - Controller as vm

Tags: javascript, angularjs, controller

Trying to get into the habit of using the controller as syntax, but seem to be missing something when trying out a simple example.

When trying to set a property like vm.name = 'John' it does not show up in my view when using {{vm.name}}.

Code is like so

controller

```
(function() {

'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .controller('HomeController', HomeController);

HomeController.$inject = ['dataService'];   

function HomeController(dataService) {


    var vm = this;

    vm.data = {};

    vm.name = 'Richard';

}
```

routes

```
'use strict';

angular
    .module('myApp')
    .config(function($routeProvider) {

    $routeProvider.when(
        '/view1', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial1.html', 
            controller: 'HomeController',
            controllerAs: 'vm'
        });
    $routeProvider.when(
        '/view2', 
        {
            templateUrl: 'partials/partial2.html'

        });
    $routeProvider.otherwise(
        {
            redirectTo: '/view1'
        });
});
```

view

```
<p>View 1</p>

<h1>Hello {{ vm.name }}</h1>
```

Comment: did you initialize the app in the html?

Answer (score 0):

Not sure if you are using angular version more than 1.3, here is the working [`Plunker`](http://jsfiddle.net/sajeetharan/emz3mj93/2/)

Your HomeController should be changed like this,

```
app.controller("HomeController", function(){
    this.name="Richard";
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Use $scope. I think it will work. Write your code:

```
function HomeController(dataService) {

var vm = this;

vm.data = {};

vm.name = 'Richard';}
```

using [$scope](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope), try this one:

```
function HomeController($scope, dataService) {

$scope.data = {};

$scope.name = 'Richard';}
```

view

```
<p>View 1</p>
<h1>Hello {{name}}</h1>
```

Please read [this](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/controller) article too!!!

Comment: OP wants to use controller as and not scope. This is not the answer he is looking for

Answer (score 0):

You need to declare variables on the $scope object to achieve two way bindings. Otherwise its just a regular javascript variables.  The scope is like a glue between your view and controller in angularjs.[Read Here](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/scope).

Answer (score 0):

The only thing I can see as an issue is that you dont have ngRoute module included...

```
 var app = angular.module('plunker', [
  'ngRoute'
 ]);
```

or your dataservice isnt included as a script which is making the injection fail. Based off the information you have included I created a working [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/N7UURSWMi55l79HJC7pu?p=preview) for you using the view-model concept instead of $scope.

Heres angulars best practices which has some very useful information and examples on using the view-model concept, accompanied by a lot of other information [Angular Guide](https://github.com/johnpapa/angular-styleguide)